# qt add a database sql into a project imported from cmake

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Normally, to add a database to qt, we would go to the .pro file and add sql, but the project am working on was imported from cmake, so it does not have a .pro file. Rather it has a CMakeLists.txt file and i want to connect it to an sqlite database. Can anyone help me out. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the issue. I generate my Qt projects with `CMake` and I use `sqlite` databases. I don't remember doing anything special to make it work except for the sqldrivers folder.

Answer (score 19):

It's `Sql` component to add to the `find_package()` command and `Qt5::Sql` to the `target_link_libraries()` command.

Search for something like that:

```
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Quick Sql)
```

or like that:

```
find_package(Qt5Sql REQUIRED)
```

And the `target_link_libraries()`:

```
target_link_libraries(myprogram Qt5::Core Qt5::Quick Qt5::Sql)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, very grateful.

Comment: for recent version, you need to add this Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Sql

Answer (score 0):

I searched for a very long time for a solution to the undefined symbol error with QSqlDatabase and tried many a different cmake setting ranging from link_directories over set(SQLite_DIR and get_target_property to aux_source_directory. Turns out it really suffices to use the above mentioned two additions to the cmakelists file. But you need  to do a complete clean to make it work on the Mac. Delete the Debug/ Release directory.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is inthe qt docs. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqlquery.html

CMake:
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Sql)
target_link_libraries(mytarget PRIVATE Qt6::Sql)

Header:
`#include <QSqlQuery>`

So, you add the two lines to CMakeLists.txt then you can include the #include  in your declaration file.

- Remember to change "mytarget" to your project name.
- Put the"findpackage" with the other findpackages and the
  "target_link_library" later in the file with the other
  target_link_library declarations.